# Dynamic loading of JavaScript file not working as expected

Tags: javascript, performance, settimeout

I am loading javascript file dynamically to speed up performance of my page. The code is

```
 <head>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function includeJS(){
     var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
     scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
     scriptElement.src = "script/TestScript.js";
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
     testFunction();
     }
 </script>
 </head>
```

The testFunction() is present inside the TestScript.js. So it is throwing an error like 'testFunction() is undefined' as the JavaScript file is not completely loaded. So I tried with setTimeout function to fix it. The code is

```
setTimeOut('testFunction()',1000);
```

Its working fine now. But I can not put the delay time 1000 in server as the JavaScript file loading is depends on the internet speed and file size. So is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: Put it in an onload handler. `scriptElement.onload = function(){window.testFunction();}`

Comment: Have you tried adding an `onload` listener?